# Issues with PHP/MySQL loop

Tags: php, mysql, grid-system

I'm working on a loop within a grid system that displays 2 grid rows of 3 inline images at a time (pagination). I've been trying to debug my code to display `<div id="clear"></div>` after every 3 returned MySQL rows, but haven't been successful.

**PHP/HTML**

```
<ul class="clean" style="width:940px; height:465px;">
  <?php
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images");
  $i=0;
  //Begin image loop
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  //Start counter
  $i++;
  $n = ($i + 5);
  $class = "";
  $clear = "";

  //Generate classes 
  if (($i % 3) == 1){
      $class = "alpha";
  }
  if (($i % 3) == 0){
      $class = "omega";
  }

  //Generate list items
  if (($n % 6) == 0){?>

  <li class="clearfix"> 
    <?php }if (($i % 4) == 0){?>
    <div id="clear"></div>
    <?php }?>
    <div class="grid_4 <?php echo $class;?>">
      <p><a href="<?php echo $row["src"];?>" alt="<?php echo $row["alt"];?>">
      <img src="<?php echo $row["src"];?>" alt="<?php echo $row["alt"];?>" />
      </a><br />
      <small class="center"><?php echo $row["excerpt"];?></small></p>
    </div>
    <?php if (($i % 6) == 0){?>
  </li> 
  <!-- //slide --> 
  <?php }} //End image loop?>
</ul>
```

How I have my grid set up is, within each grid row from left to right, there is an `alpha` class assigned to the first element and an `omega` class assigned to the last.  In order to display `<div id="clear"></div>` after every 3 returned MySQL rows technically, this should work:

**Generated list items**

```
<?php 
if (($n % 6) == 0){?>

<li class="clearfix"> 
<?php }if (($i % 4) == 0){?>
  <div id="clear"></div>
<?php }?>
```

However it doesn't.  Within 6 returned grid rows equaling 18 total images, it generates `<div id="clear"></div>` fine after MySQL rows 1-3 and after 13-15, but for MySQL rows 6-9,`<div id="clear"></div>` displays after MySQL row 6 where it should be displaying after 9.

I hope this makes sense, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am working on a solution but I did notice something worth mentioning. You should change your `id='clear'` to `class='clear'` since there will be more then one. Your `<div>` might need a `&nbsp;` to make sure all browsers know the div is there, this could be optional but it's good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if something like this would work for you.

```
<?php
$i = 1;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images");

$max_count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($max_count > 0)
{
?>
<ul>
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($i % 3 == 1) {
        $class = 'alpha';
    } elseif($i % 3 == 0) {
        $class = 'omega';
    } else {
        $class = ''; //Do NOT carry through the loops
    }

    if($i % 6 == 1 || $i == 1) {
?>
    <li>
<?php
    }
?>
        <div class="grid_4 <?php echo $class ?>">
            <p>
                <a href="<?php echo $row["src"];?>" alt="<?php echo $row["alt"];?>"><img src="<?php echo $row["src"];?>" alt="<?php echo $row["alt"];?>" /></a>
                <br />
                <small class="center"><?php echo $row["excerpt"];?></small>
            </p>
        </div>
<?php
    if($i % 3 == 0) {
?>
        <div class='clear'>&nbsp;</div>
<?php
    }

    if($i % 6 == 0 || $i == $max_count) {
?>
    </li>
<?php
    }

    $i++; //Move Row Count Along
}
?>
</ul>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I think it has to do with your `if (($i % 4) == 0)` statement. You should use modulus by 3, not by 4. **This will give your a `<div id="clear"></div>` on the first row though.**

In order to prevent that, you can say:

`if ((($i % 3) == 0) && $i != 0)`

Give it a try, let me know if it works for you!

Comment: Thanks dykeag, this is close, `<div id="clear"></div>` is displaying one MySQL row higher e.g. after the second MySQL row instead of the third, but it's displaying uniform within each generated grid row set.

Comment: Well that is simple enough to fix! You can just change your if-statement slightly so it looks more like this: `if ((($i % 3) == 1) && $i != 0)`. You might have to change the `$i != 0` part to `$i != 1`, if you are getting `<div id="clear"></div>` after the first or second image.